# How do I add ApplicationServices so I can #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>?

Tags: cocoa

Apple's Image I/O programming guide says:

> Image I/O resides in the Application
>   Services framework in Mac OS X, and in
>   the Image I/O framework in iOS. After
>   adding the framework to your
>   application, import the header file by
>   including this statement:
>
> #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

I must be "adding the framework" wrong because when I add the #import line to my code and compile I get an error "ImageIO/ImageIO.h: No such file or directory". Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I did the following in Xcode to get the error.

1. New Project (OS X Cocoa Application)
2. In the "Groups & Files" tree select MyProjectName/Frameworks/Other Frameworks...
3. Right click and select Add > Existing Frameworks
4. Under "Mac OSX 10.6 SDK" in the dialog that appears, choose "ApplicationServices.framework"
5. In MyProjectName.m (or any other file) add #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

I'm using Xcode 3.2.3 on OS X 10.6.4 and have 10.6 SDK (10M2262).

I've also tried adding the framework using Project > Add to Project.. and choosing the framework from the SDK and from /System/Library/Frameworks and get the error in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

You've added the framework correctly. What's causing your problem is that you shouldn't import ImageIO's header specifically; you should import the ApplicationServices header.

You may want to file a bug against the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I've reported the typo using the "It's good but..." link at the bottom of Apple's docuemtation page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar experience, as I am still on XCode 3.2, in addition to what is said above, I had to use the Foundation tool template when creating a new project, so I suspect everything would have been good if I had added the Foundation framework to the make file.

But when stuff like this happens, then I drop into XCode, and tries to solve it from there.

Comment: ImageIO doesn't require Foundation. It requires Core Foundation, which Foundation uses and whose headers Foundation's headers include. For that matter, I would be surprised if ApplicationServices didn't indirectly bring in CF just as well.

Comment: That may very well be so, but I know I haven't messed with anything, and it really did work for me. (You'll have to fire up XCode 3.2 to prove me wrong, so just take my word for it. ) I really didn't try to make a Foundation tool, before "everything else was tested", with regards to frameworks, and header files.